# Don't print space after last number

Tags: c++

**LANGUAGE: C++**
Hello, in the following function (code block) i have written a line to print an space between characters but **i don't want print spaces after last characters**. How can i solve this problem?

```
bool perfecto(int n)
{
    int suma, i;
    suma = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0) 
        {
            suma += i;
            cout << i << " ";
        }
    }
    if (suma == n)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Best regards.
Ángel Manuel.

Comment: [A blog post with example](http://jaysprenkle.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/the-delimited-list-builder-pattern/)

Answer (score 16):

The simplest way would be to turn the problem around: if you only print spaces before printing the number (and not after) then it becomes how not to print the first time, which is much easier.

I'll let you figure it out :)

Answer (score 4):

```
bool perfecto(int n)
{
    int suma, i;
    suma = 0;
    bool first = true;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0) 
        {
            suma += i;

            if ( !first )
            {
                cout << " ";
            }

            cout << i;

            first = false;
        }
    }
    if (suma == n)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either check if i is equal to n - 1 and not print it in that case, or something like

```
std::cout << "1";
for (int i = 2; i < n; ++i)
{
    std::cout << " " << i;
}
```

In the second case, you have to watch for for a case where n is 1 or less

Comment: He isn't printing all numbers, just the factors.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of options. In this case, probably the easiest is to print spaces BEFORE elements except the first and use a flag to track the first element:

```
bool perfecto(int n)
{
    int suma, i;
    suma = 0;
    bool first = true;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0) 
        {
            suma += i;
            if(!first)
            {
                std::cout << " ";
            }
            else first = false;
            cout << i;
        }
    }
    if (suma == n)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

EDIT: Other popular alternatives are printing the first item and no delimiter outside the loop completely and then inside the loop you can always pre-print the item with no if-check at all. This approach wouldn't work as well with your loop though since you don't always know when the first item will print. You can also create wrapper `ostream` like classes that keep track of their internal printing state and know when to put the spaces.

Comment: In these cases, instead of having a bool and an if statement, I like to have a `char * space = ""` before the loop, and then at the end of the loop put `space = " "`. It may make a tiny performance difference or none at all, but I think it's more readable.

Answer (score -2):

Replace this line: `cout << i << " ";`
with:

```
cout << i;

if (i == n-1)
  cout << endl;
else
  cout << " ";
```

Comment: Counter-example: n = 6, output is `1 2 3 `. Your code doesn't eliminate the trailing space.