# How to deal with last comma, when making comma separated string?

Tags: c++, string, boost, stringstream, csv

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Don't print space after last number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005115/dont-print-space-after-last-number)
>   [Printing lists with commas C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496982/printing-lists-with-commas-c)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   vector<int> VecInts;

   VecInts.push_back(1);
   VecInts.push_back(2);
   VecInts.push_back(3);
   VecInts.push_back(4);
   VecInts.push_back(5);

   stringstream ss;
   BOOST_FOREACH(int i, VecInts)
   {
      ss << i << ",";
   }

   cout << ss.str();

   return 0;
}
```

This prints out: `1,2,3,4,5,`
However I want: `1,2,3,4,5`

How can I achieve that in an **elegant** way?

I see there is some confusion about what I mean with "elegant": E.g. no slowing down "if-clause" in my loop. Imagine 100.000 entries in the vector! If that is all you have to offer, I'd rather remove the last comma after I have gone through the loop.

Comment: I've always wondered about this as well.

Comment: @Matthieu that's not a dupe, I think. When using `BOOST_FOREACH` there is no obvious way for detecting the start or end (you can't simply check `index == 0` or `it == c.begin()` or something). So I wouldn't close this one as a dupe.

Comment: @Johannes: I find the answer to be "BOOST_FOREACH" agnostic. The simplest way seems to be keeping an alternative variable on the side whatever the iteration method and... turn the problem on its head and detect the *first* iteration instead of the last.

Comment: You could try our [pretty printer](http://louisdx.github.com/cxx-prettyprint/) for all containers :-)

Comment: @Matt but that would be the wrong way for a `for(int i = ..; i < ...; i++)` loop, and the wrong way for a `for(iterator i = ..` loop too. Both loops can just compare `i` to `..`, instead of introducing an alternative variable. The difficulty in this question is that there is no iterator and no index variable to use. Voted for reopen. These questions are related, but I don't think they are "exact duplicates"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

How about this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> v;

   v.push_back(1);
   v.push_back(2);
   v.push_back(3);
   v.push_back(4);
   v.push_back(5);

   std::ostringstream ss;
   if(!v.empty()) {
      std::copy(v.begin(), std::prev(v.end()), std::ostream_iterator<int>(ss, ", "));
      ss << v.back();
   }
   std::cout << ss.str() << "\n";
}
```

No need to add extra variables and doesn't even depend on boost! Actually, in addition to the "no additional variable in the loop" requirement, one could say that there is not even a loop :)

Comment: This is the best answer I have seen so far, and I have not seen it in any of the suggested duplicates!

Comment: I added a `if(v.empty()) return;` line, changed the whole thing into a template function, wrote some tests, and I'm really happy with it. It will go straight to my `StrUtils.hpp` header. ;-) If I don't see any unexpected objections coming up, this will soon be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 16):

Detecting the one before last is always tricky, detecting the first is very easy.

```
bool first = true;
stringstream ss;
BOOST_FOREACH(int i, VecInts)
{
  if (!first) { ss << ","; }
  first = false;
  ss << i;
}
```

Comment: Now that's a real alternative approach!

Answer (score 10):

Using Karma from Boost Spirit - has a reputation for being fast.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v;
  v.push_back(1);
  v.push_back(2);
  v.push_back(3);

  using namespace boost::spirit::karma;
  std::cout << format(int_ % ',', v) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: In fact it has reputation of actually being faster than iostreams (which are quite slow in some standard library implementations).

Comment: This is also a very nice solution. But I had to choose, and I feel for the "pure stl" version. Shame on me. ;-)

Comment: I don't blame you - Karma is a bit heavyweight if all you want to do is print some ints!

Comment: I benchmarked it, comparing it to the "pure stl" version using 10000 `int`'s. windows, gcc, release version: PureStl: 126, Boost:2658. (I'm not sure if I made a reliable test though.)

Comment: @AudioDroid: did you make sure to compile with optimizations on ? Karma relies a lot on heavy template machinery, so it relies a lot on optimization to get decent speed.

Comment: For reference: As much as I admire Boost.Spirit, a simple addition like this added 5 seconds to the compilation time (from 0.4s to 4.5s with gcc and from 0.6 to 5.6 with clang).

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
if (ss.tellp ())
{
   ss << ",";
}
ss << i;
```

Alternatively, if the "if" is making you worried:

```
char *comma = "";
BOOST_FOREACH(int i, VecInts)
{
   ss << comma << i;
   comma = ",";
}
```

Comment: If you made that correct C++, you'd have seen it's nowhere near elegant.

Comment: @Jan: OK, it's now valid C++ rather than simple pseudo-code.

Comment: @PoweRoy: It's not deleting anything -- it's adding before and not adding the initial one.

Comment: Wow. I really like the second idea. Brilliant. :-D. Hm, than again I assign comma every time. :-/

Comment: @AudioDroid: The assignment should just be a single 'mov' instruction when processed by the optimiser.

Comment: @AudioDroid: Don't worry about optimization say 97% of the time... You worry about assigning a `char const*` when right next to it you're performing two function calls in a row... you'll not notice in the noise.

Comment: @Jan, indeed it is just adding it. Well I gues i missed it :P

Comment: This second solution here is one of the few general purpose solutions in this entire thread.  The rest break down if you deviate even slightly from "print a vector of number to a string stream".  I really like it.  I suppose Matthieu M.'s solution is also general purpose (maybe even more general), but this one is one line shorter and in my opinion twice as pretty.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I like a solution that does not cause potential memory allocations (because the string grows larger than needed). An extra-if within the loop body should be tractable thanks to branch target buffering, but I would do so:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    using std::cout;
    typedef std::vector<int>::iterator iterator;

    std::vector<int> ints;    
    ints.push_back(5);
    ints.push_back(1);
    ints.push_back(4);
    ints.push_back(2);
    ints.push_back(3);


    if (!ints.empty()) {
        iterator        it = ints.begin();
        const iterator end = ints.end();

        cout << *it;
        for (++it; it!=end; ++it) {
            cout << ", " << *it;
        }
        cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, BYORA (bring your own re-usable algorithm):

```
// Follow the signature of std::getline. Allows us to stay completely
// type agnostic.
template <typename Stream, typename Iter, typename Infix>
inline Stream& infix (Stream &os, Iter from, Iter to, Infix infix_) {
    if (from == to) return os;
    os << *from;
    for (++from; from!=to; ++from) {
        os << infix_ << *from;
    }
    return os;
}

template <typename Stream, typename Iter>
inline Stream& comma_seperated (Stream &os, Iter from, Iter to) {
    return infix (os, from, to, ", ");
}
```

so that

```
...
comma_seperated(cout, ints.begin(), ints.end()) << std::endl;

infix(cout, ints.begin(), ints.end(), "-") << std::endl;
infix(cout, ints.begin(), ints.end(), "> <") << std::endl;
...
```

output:

```
5, 1, 4, 2, 3
5-1-4-2-3
5> <1> <4> <2> <3
```

The neat thing is it works for every output stream, any container that has forward iterators, with any infix, and with any infix type (interesting e.g. when you use wide strings).

Comment: The infix method lacks initial check for `from == to` (I was not the one to downvote and don't think such trivial omission is reason to downvote).

Comment: You're right. Will fix this :)

Comment: @phresnel: Actually I think it would even work with an `InputIterator`, like `std::cin` for example. The tricky part with those being not eating up a supplementary argument :/

Answer (score 3):

I like moving the test outside the loop.
It only needs to be done once. So do it first.

Like this:

```
if (!VecInts.empty())
{
    ss << VecInts[0]

    for(any loop = ++(VecInts.begin()); loop != VecInts.end(); ++loop)
    {
        ss << "," << *loop;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either trim the string at the end, or using single for loop instead of foreach and dont concatenate at the last iteration

Comment: going back is not always possible (think printing to logs). Stopping before the end means you can detect the end (not possible on forward iterators ranges).

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you format into a `stringstream` anyway, you can just trim the resulting string by one character:

```
cout << ss.str().substr(0, ss.str().size() - 1);
```

If the string is empty, than the second argument says -1, which means everything and does not crash and if the string is non-empty, it always ends with a comma.

But if you write to an output stream directly, I never found anything better than the `first` flag.

That is unless you want to use `join` from [boost.string algo](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/join.html).

Comment: `boost::join(...)` sounds very promising. Would you mind providing an example with the given context?

Comment: @AudioDroid: `boost::join(boost::make_transform_iterator(v, boost::lexical_cast<std::string, int>), ",")` should do the trick (using more bits from boost), but I am not too sure this is sufficient to use the lexical cast.

Comment: (at)Jan Hudec: Unfortunately my compiler doesn't like code. Maybe I would need the compiled version of boost. I only have the features that work without compiling the library. :-/

Answer (score 0):

This would work

```
stringstream ss;
BOOST_FOREACH(int const& i, VecInts)
{
   if(&i != &VecInts[0])
     ss << ", ";
   ss << i;
}
```

I suspect with "elegant" you mean "without introducing a new variable". But I think I would just do it "non-elegant" if I couldn't find anything else. It's still clear

```
stringstream ss;
bool comma = false;
BOOST_FOREACH(int i, VecInts)
{
   if(comma)
     ss << ", ";
   ss << i;
   comma = true;
}
```

> Imagine 100.000 entries in the vector! If that is all you have to offer, I'd rather remove the last comma after I have gone thorough the loop.

You are saying that as if printing `ss << i` is one machine instruction. Come on, executing that expression will execute lots of `if`'s and loops inside. Your `if` will be nothing compared to that.

Answer (score -2):

`cout << ss.str()<<"\b" <<" ";`

You can add the "\b" backspace

This will overwrite the extra "," .

for Example :

```
int main()
{
    cout<<"Hi";
    cout<<'\b';  //Cursor moves 1 position backwards
    cout<<" ";   //Overwrites letter 'i' with space
}
```

So the output would be

```
H
```

Comment: That won't delete anything. It will only move the output cursor one to the left.

Comment: @phresnel I meant to do this , corrected my solution Thank you :)

Comment: There is still "this will delete" in there

Comment: @phresnel is this right now ?

Comment: It will also not overwrite it, unfortunately. \b is entirely a "output cursor control char", it does nothing to the input.

Comment: @xsari3x: The output will be "Hi\b ". It will render on terminal as "H ", but that's totally irrelevant, because the output is probably meant to be interpreted by something (downvoting, the answer is IMHO bogus).