# Accessing elements from map<key, set<datatype>>

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, set

I am working with a data structure that looks like this:

```
map<string, set<string>> data;
```

By now, I had no problems with working with the map by using foreach cycle, however, now I  need to print out the data from the map like this:

```
KEY: elem1, elem2, elem3
KEY2: elem1, elem2, elem3
```

Because of the missing comma at the end, I cannot quite use the foreach cycle anymore (can I?). Since I am new to C++, C++11 and all the fun it offers, I am quite lost.
I came up with:

```
for ( auto i : data )
{
    cout << i.first << ": ";
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < /* size of the set */ - 1; i ++ )
        cout << j << ", ";

    cout << /* the last element of the set */ << endl;
}
```

I know what I want, I just have no idea about syntax and the C++ reference is not helping much. 
Thanks for answers, meanwhile I am going to browse the C++ reference myself.

Comment: won't work for 1-element set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically (across several languages) use a delimiter that I initialize to an empty string and then change in the loop:

```
for (auto& i : data) {
    std::cout << i.first << ": ";

    std::string delim;     
    for (auto& s : i.second) {
        std::cout << delim << s;

        delim = ", ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[Output (live demo on coliru):](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8374e31b2af974de)

```
KEY: elem1, elem2, elem3
KEY1: elem1, elem2, elem3
```

[Another solution is to use ostream iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692880/how-to-deal-with-last-comma-when-making-comma-separated-string)

Comment: This is perfect and going to be useful two times a week for me. Thanks a lot <3

Comment: Well, but this adds an additional string assignment for each loop iteration. It may not make a difference in performance in most situations, but it still strikes me as a rather radical approach! :)

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I must admit I was surprised at this too; though I guess that in scripting languages it makes little difference, in C++ (where performance is generally more in focus), it is more flashy.

Answer (score 4):

A pattern I often use (with `BOOST_FOREACH`), is:

```
bool first = true;
for (auto const& e: collection) {
    if (first) { first = false; } else { out << ", "; }
    ...
}
```

There is a STL way of doing this though, using `ostream_iterator`:

```
std::copy(collection.begin(), collection.end(),
          std::ostream_iterator<value_type>(out, ", "));
```

and so your example becomes:

```
for (auto const& pair: map) {
    out << pair.first << ": ";

    std::copy(pair.second.begin(), pair.second.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(out, ", "));
}
```

but honestly, I still feel like using the `bool first = true` approach is more readable.

Comment: +1 for the interesting `ostream_iterator` technique.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider code like this (which uses a flag to print the first string in the set in a different way than the following strings, that are instead prefixed with `", "`).

Note that since you are *observing* the elements in the containers, you may want to use `const auto&` in the range-for loops.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Fill the data structure with some test data
    map<string, set<string>> data;
    data["Key1"].emplace("hello");
    data["Key1"].emplace("world");
    data["Key1"].emplace("test");
    data["Key2"].emplace("Ciao");
    data["Key2"].emplace("Mondo");

    // For each item in the outer map
    for (const auto& x : data) {
        // Print item's key
        cout << x.first << ": ";

        // Special output for the first string in the set
        bool first = true;

        // Note: x.first is the key, x.second is the associated set.

        // For each string in the set:
        for (const auto& s : x.second) {
            // Prefix every string except the first one with ", "
            if (!first) {
                cout << ", ";
            } else {
                first = false;
            }

            // Print current string in the set
            cout << s;
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Live on Ideone](http://ideone.com/Vftl2x)

Output:

> ```
> Key1: hello, test, world
> Key2: Ciao, Mondo
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I typically use iterators to *join* strings.

```
for (auto& i : data) {
    cout << i.first << ':';
    auto p = i.second.begin();
    auto q = i.second.end();
    if (p != q) {
        cout << ' ' << *p;
        for (++p; p != q; ++p) {
            cout << ", " << *p;
        }
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't find a "perfect" solution. Basically, you want to do the same thing for every element (by virtue of the range-based for loop) but still handle one case in a different way. That doesn't go together. One thing you could do is use an additional flag to handle the first element differently:

```
bool first_element = true;
for ( auto i : data )
{
    if ( !first_element)
    {
        // print ","
    }
    // print i;    

    first_element = false;
}
```

Generally, don't worry too much about it if this is just a small piece of code in some isolated place somewhere in your project.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename R>
struct not_last_t {
  R r;
  not_last_t(R&& in):r(std::forward<R>(in)){}
  not_last_t(not_last_t&&)=default;
  void operator=(not_last_t&&)=delete;
  // C++14 because lazy.  Can be written in C++11:
  auto begin() { using std::begin; return begin(r); }
  auto end() {
    using std::end; auto ret=end(r); 
    if(ret==begin()) return ret;
    return std::next(ret,-1);
  }
};
template<typename R>
not_last_t<R> not_last(R&&r){return {sts::forward<R>(r);}}
```

use:

```
for(auto x:not_last(s))
  std::cout << x << ", ";
if (!s.empty())
  std::cout << s.back();
```

efficient and clear at point of use.  Bulky in library.

Uses some C++14 features, because I am lazy, and probably full of typos.  If there is interest I can clean the code up.